# Why do I get a "indexed columns are not unique" error when trying to add a UNIQUE INDEX to a SQLite Table?

Tags: sqlite, unique-index

When attempting to create an unique index with the following syntax:

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Table_Index ON Table (CharColumn, IntColumn)`

Why do I receive the error:

`indexed columns are not unique`

Comment: Someone else had the same problem, but their question was unanswered: https://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg68695.html

Comment: It's telling you why -- because the columns that you are trying to make into a UNIQUE INDEX are not unique.

Comment: It's a pretty lousy error message. It really means that there are some repeated values for that column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error "indexed columns are not unique" because the indexed columns are not unique, that is, there are some duplicate records.

Use a query like this to find out which records:

```sql
SELECT CharColumn,
       IntColumn,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY CharColumn,
         IntColumn
HAVING Count > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table have already containing rows, then probably you have a 2 or more rows with the same values indicated in your tables unique index (CharColumn, IntColumn)

e.g.
 row     CharColumn     IntColumn
10       ABC             1
21       ABC             1

A unique index means no more than 1 rows should contains the value.